# Expression.Call and Count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, dynamic

I'm looking for a way to do following dynamically:

```
var q = context.Subscription
               .Include("Client")
               .Include("Invoices")
                Where(s=>s.Client.Invoices.Count(i=>i.InvoiceID == SomeInt) > 0);
```

I would like to build expression dynamically for the left side:

```
Expression left = s => s.Client.Invoices.Count(i => i.InvoiceID == iSomeVar); //!
Expression right = Expression.Constant(0);
var binary = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
```

Thanks!

**UPDATED NOTES:**

Please note: The end result must be

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

**Simple version:**

```
// To give clear idea, all what I want to achieve is to determine 
// whether specific record exists in reference table using known Path. 
// Ultimately I want to extend following function (which works great by 
// the way, but for simple operations)

static Expression CreateExpression<T>(string propertyPath, 
                                      object propertyValue, 
                                      ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
{
     PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
     MemberExpression left = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, property);
     ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant(0);
     BinaryExpression binary = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);

     return binary;
}

// And I want to call this function and get result exactly as shown below:

Expression result = 
           CreateExpression<Subscription>("Client.Invoices.InvoiceID", 
                                          theID,
                                          valueSelector.Parameters.Single());

// Where result will be: 
//       t => t.Client.Invoices.Count(i => i.InvoiceID == theID) > 0;
```

**Extended version:**

```
// 1) I'm using Silverlight 4, EF, RIA.

// 2) At the server side I have a function GetSubscriptionsByCriteria
//   that looks about it:

public IQueryable<Subscription> GetSubscriptionsByCriteria(...)
{
      var query = this.ObjectContext.Subscriptions.Include("Client")
                                                  .Include("Client.Invoices");
      var criteria = BuildCriteria(...);
      return query.Where(criteria)
}

// 3) BuildCriteria(...) function gathers Expressions and 
//    aggregates it into the single Expression with different 
//    AND/OR conditions, something like that:

public Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> BuildCriteria(
                      List<SearchFilter> filters,
                      Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> valueSelector)
{
    List<Expression> filterExpressions = new List<Expression>();
    ...
    Expression expr = CreateExpression<Subscription>(
                                   sfItem.DBPropertyName, 
                                   sfItem.DBPropertyValue, 
                                   paramExpression, 
                                   sf.SearchCondition);
    filterExpressions.Add(expr);
    ...

    var filterBody = 
        filterExpressions.Aggregate<Expression>(
                (accumulate, equal) => Expression.And(accumulate, equal));
   return Expression
           .Lambda<Func<Subscription, bool>>(filterBody, paramExpression);
}

// 4) Here is the simplified version of CreateExpression function:

 static Expression CreateExpression<T>(string propertyName, 
                                       object propertyValue, 
                                       ParameterExpression paramExpression)
 {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant(0);
        MemberExpression left = Expression.Property(paramExpression, property);

        return binary = Expression.Equals(left, right);
 }
```

So, I hope it's clear now why do I need Expression for the left side in my original post. Trying to make this as DRY as possible.

P.S. Not to make it too confusing here is why I think I need to do ёExpression.Call(...)ё:
When I run following code and break it to see DebugView I notice this:

```
Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> predicate = 
           t => t.Client.Invoices.Count(i => i.InvoiceID == 5) > 0;
BinaryExpression eq = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;
var left = eq.Left; // <-- See DEBUG VIEW
var right = eq.Right;   

// DEBUG VIEW:
// Arguments: Count = 2
//            [0] = {t.Client.Invoices}
//            [1] = {i => (i.InvoiceID == 5)}
// DebugView: ".Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(
//               ($t.Client).ClientInvoices,
//               .Lambda#Lambda1<System.Func`2[SLApp.Web.Invoice,System.Boolean]>)
//               .Lambda#Lambda1<System.Func`2[SLApp.Web.Invoice,System.Boolean]>
//               (SLApp.Web.ClientInvoice $i){ $i.ClientInvoiceID == 5 }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working program that does what I think you'd like.  It defines a function that takes a path to an integer property inside a collection, and an integer value.  It then checks whether or not that collection has Count > 0 of that value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;

namespace Test_Console
{
    public class Subscription
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Invoice
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subscriptions = new[]
            {
                new Subscription { Id = 1, Client = new Client { Invoices = new [] {
                    new Invoice { Id = 1 },
                    new Invoice { Id = 2 },
                    new Invoice { Id = 5 }
                } } },
                new Subscription { Id = 2, Client = new Client { Invoices = new [] {
                    new Invoice { Id = 4 },
                    new Invoice { Id = 5 },
                    new Invoice { Id = 5 }
                } } },
                new Subscription { Id = 3, Client = new Client { Invoices = new Invoice[] {
                } } },
            };

            var propertyPath = "Client.Invoices.Id";
            Console.WriteLine("What Id would you like to check " + propertyPath + " for?");
            var propertyValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var whereNumberOne = makeWhere<Subscription>(propertyPath, propertyValue);

            Console.WriteLine("The following Subscription objects match:");
            foreach (var s in subscriptions.Where(whereNumberOne).ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: " + s.Id);
            }
        }

        private static Func<T, bool> makeWhere<T>(string propertyPath, int propertyValue)
        {
            string[] navigateProperties = propertyPath.Split('.');

            var currentType = typeof(T);
            var functoidChain = new List<Func<object, object>>();
            functoidChain.Add(x => x);  // identity function starts the chain
            foreach (var nextProperty in navigateProperties)
            {
                // must be inside loop so the closer on the functoids works properly
                PropertyInfo nextPropertyInfo;

                if (currentType.IsGenericType
                 && currentType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
                {
                    nextPropertyInfo = currentType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperty(nextProperty);
                    functoidChain.Add(x =>
                        ((IEnumerable<object>)x)
                        .Count(y => (int)nextPropertyInfo.GetValue(y, null) == propertyValue)
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    nextPropertyInfo = currentType.GetProperty(nextProperty);
                    functoidChain.Add(x => nextPropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null));
                }
                currentType = nextPropertyInfo.PropertyType;
            }
            // compose the functions together
            var composedFunctoidChain = functoidChain.Aggregate((f, g) => x => g(f(x)));
            var leftSide = new Func<T, int>(x => (int)composedFunctoidChain(x));
            return new Func<T, bool>(r => leftSide(r) > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the link you've provided does not relate to the problem I've encounter

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back on this, however the solution you provided still doesn't resolve the issue. I seriously need an Expression for the left side and I try to explain why in post above.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're doing now, good job explaining that better.  I'm still not sure you need expressions and I'll tell you why.  You're always using > 0 on your right side, so that's constant.  If you were varying that, then you should make it dynamic.  It's not better design to make everything dynamic.  The best design, in my opinion, just solves the problem as simply and as DRYly as possible.  I'll edit my answer, let me know what you think in a little bit.

Comment: Thank you Milimetric, well, the code I've provided is very simplified, I just want to understand how to create more complex expression tree that works in specific scenario, there are so many samples I saw and tried from various places but none worked for me.

Comment: Ok, check out my latest.  You can change it to be more dynamic where you need it, but it works as long as all the lambda related variables are defined inside the loop so the closure works as you'd expect when they evaluate.

Comment: I appreciate your effort Milimetric very much! But I got myself into another problem now, how to convert Func<T, bool> into Expression? It's because I need to integrate the code into CreateExpression<T> function I've described above, otherwise I end up with copy/pasting/adjusting just about 1k custom filtering functions which roughly just over 20k lines of hardcode.

Comment: That's a little confusing, why are there 20k lines of hard coded functions?  I thought BuildCriteria and CreateExpression were the only two functions you needed.  If you want to turn it into Expression, you'd use pretty much the same logic, it seems like you already know what you're doing from the code.  If you don't, I don't recommend you go forward with code you don't understand.

Comment: Though I do see an ugly hack by passing IQueryable<T> as the reference into BuildCriteria and appending the result from your code into it... let me check

Comment: But just take Func<T, bool> as a return from CreateExpression (makeWhere in my code) and aggregate those the same way you aggregate the expressions.  The end result that you really need is still Func<T, bool> right?

Comment: The end result that I need is Expression<Func<T, bool>>, just as is stands in my post: public IQueryable<Subscription> GetSubscriptionsByCriteria ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you closer to what you're going for:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateAnyExpression<T, T2>(string propertyPath, 
                                    Expression<Func<T2, bool>> matchExpression)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "s");
    var propertyNames = propertyPath.Split('.');
    Expression propBase = parameterExpression;
    foreach(var propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        propBase = Expression.Property(propBase, property);
        type = propBase.Type;
    }
    var itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    // .Any(...) is better than .Count(...) > 0
    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
        .Single(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(itemType);
    var callToAny = Expression.Call(anyMethod, propBase, matchExpression);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(callToAny, parameterExpression);
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
CreateAnyExpression<Subscription, Invoice>("Client.Invoices", i => i.InvoiceID == 1)
```

... yields the following `Expression<Func<Subscription,bool>>`:

```
s => s.Client.Invoices.Any(i => (i.InvoiceID == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working program building Linq Expression

```
{(x.Children.Count(y => y.SomeID == SomeVar) > 0)}
```

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExpressionTree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterExpression foundX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Parent), "x");
            Guid[] guids = new Guid[1] { Guid.NewGuid() };

            Expression expression = GetCountWithPredicateExpression(guids, foundX);
        }

        private static Expression GetCountWithPredicateExpression(Guid[] idsToFilter, ParameterExpression foundX)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo childIDPropertyInfo = typeof(Child).GetProperty(nameof(Child.SomeID));
            ParameterExpression foundY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Child), "y");

            Expression childIDLeft = Expression.Property(foundY, childIDPropertyInfo);
            Expression conditionExpression = Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool));

            foreach (Guid id in idsToFilter)
                conditionExpression = Expression.Or(conditionExpression, Expression.Equal(childIDLeft, Expression.Constant(id)));

            Expression<Func<Child, bool>> idLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Child, bool>>(conditionExpression, foundY);

            var countMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                .First(method => method.Name == "Count" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Child));

            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo childrenPropertyInfo = typeof(Parent).GetProperty("Children");
            Expression childrenLeft = Expression.Property(foundX, childrenPropertyInfo);

            Expression ret = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(countMethod, childrenLeft, idLambda), Expression.Constant(0));

            return ret;
        }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public Child[] Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Guid SomeID { get; set; }
    }
}
```