# Build dynamic Expression for search

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, expression, ria

I'm in trouble, can't figure out seems a very simple thing that in plain SQL can be done within 1 minute, it's been several hours so far. Here is the situation:

- I have single field where user may enter as many words as he/she likes
- I need to build Expression to find match
- Let's say there are 3 fields in database: firstname, middlename, lastname
- I need to split the search entry and compare against those 3 fields
- I'm dealing with Silverlight RIA, EF
- Once again search entry contains UNKNOWN number of words

Here under what I'm trying to accomplish, return type is mandatory:

```
public Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> GetSearchExpression(string text)
{
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> result;

    var keywords = text.Trim().Split(" ");
    foreach(var keyword in keywords)
    {
         // TODO: 

         // check whether 'OR' is required (i.e. after second loop)
         // (firstname = 'keyword'
         // AND
         // middlename = 'keyword'
         // AND
         // lastname = 'keyword')
         // OR
         // (firstname like '%keyword%'
         // AND
         // middlename like '%keyword%'
         // AND
         // lastname like '%keyword%')

    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the join condition you require?

If one keyword it should be an exact match (to all three fields?)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to use Joe Albahari's [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to do something like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MyEntity>();

foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (
        p => p.FirstName.Contains (temp) && 
             p.LastName.Contains (temp) &&
             p.MiddleName.Contains (temp));
}

return predicate;
```

I left out the equality-checks because "Contains" (i.e. `like '%...%'`) will cover that possibility anyway.

I do have to point out, though, that your conditions don't make any sense, from a business logic standpoint. Under what circumstances do you want to find someone whose first, last, and middle name all contain "John"? I suspect what you really want is something more like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MyEntity>();

foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.And (
        p => p.FirstName.Contains (temp) || 
             p.LastName.Contains (temp) ||
             p.MiddleName.Contains (temp));
}

return predicate;
```

One final note: Because PredicateBuilder requires you to call `.AsExpandable()` when you are creating your query, I don't know whether this will work for you. You might have to resort to building your own expressions, which can be somewhat tedious. This can get you started, though:

```
var pParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity), "p");
var predicate = Expression.Constant(true);
foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    var keywordExpr = Expression.Constant(keyword);
    // TODO: create an expression to invoke .FirstName getter
    // TODO: create an expression to invoke string.Contains() method
    //TODO: do the same for lastname and middlename

    predicate = Expression.And(predicate, 
        Expression.Or(
            Expression.Or(firstNameContainsKeyword,
                middleNameContainsKeyword),
            lastNameContainsKeyword));
}
return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(predicate, pParam);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I think I did already try Joe Albahari's PredicateBuilder scenario and as long as I remember Invoke was not supported... as I've wrote in my post I'm dealing with IQueryable... Anyways I will try your suggestion in a morning one more time, mindless right now though feel very skeptical about building dynamic expression, it's not the first time I get across something that nobody have solution for. Here under I have posted similar question in terms of Expression builder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002131/expression-call-and-count

Comment: btw just to make it clear, I'm building expression on client side

Comment: @Max: Okay, then PredicateBuilder probably won't work out. I've always been able to accomplish what I was trying to do building expressions directly. The product I currently work on is able to do some extremely complex stuff using this approach. The trick to getting your questions answered is to make them defined and specific right at the start. If possible, narrow the question down to the one place that you are having difficulty.